# UITabBarController - more than 20 views

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I am using a tab bar (UITabBarController) on my app and I wish to have more than 20 different views to choose from.

If there are more than 5, "More" menu appears. I can access any of my views from "More" menu but I have problems with customizing my TabBar with "Configure" (Edit) navigation bar. I can see only 20 first view icons and I can't scroll the view any direction. Icon with numbers 21 or higher are unavailable in "Configure" (Edit) navigation bar

Is there a way to scroll up and down (or left and right) to be able to customize TabBar with all of my view icons? Is there the other way to customize "Configure" (Edit) navigation bar to get access to all view icons?

Comment: Why do you want to have >20 tabs? Sounds like a UI design failure…

Comment: @KennyTM Take a look at New York Times app, more than 20 tabs in a perfectly acceptable ui situation.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no solution for this :( except creating your own UITabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the controller provided by Apple, but you can work around this problem as follows:

Catches the action of the edit button and replace it with your own action that aims to display a custom screen that plays differently the sort action.

I have done this way in my applications, when I had the need.